# Черный экран при переустановке Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

В общем, записал руфусом образ десятки на флешку, выбрал систему раздела GPT, формат FAT32(при NTFS резуль тат такой же). В биосе носитель есть, выбираю его для начала загрузки, после этого наблюдаю такую картину: черный экран с точками в верхней половине[image]
При нажатии на любую клавишу скидывается до восстановления. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: похоже на неподдерживаемый видеокартой или дисплеем видеорежим или  на зависший загрузчик

Comment: попробуйте - https://superuser.com/questions/1563962/black-screen-with-colored-dots-when-trying-to-boot-from-usb-using-rufus-gpt-part